# tumblr: hide all of the post except for one special category on start/homepage

Tags: tumblr, categories

Maybe someone can help me out before I go completly nuts.

I'm trying to figure out a way to hide all postings on the tumblr start/homepage except for one single "featured" category.

I came as far as hiding all postings from the start/homepage by wrapping the tagPage around the posts. this way the posts are only shown on my static pages which is exactly what i want except the fact, that I would like to have a "featured" category so the newest postings are shown on the homepage.

Simplified this is what i got right now:
    {block:TagPage}
    {block:Posts}
    {block:Text}{/block:Text}
    {block:/Posts}
    {block:/TagPage}

I would really really appreciate any help! thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solutions:

**API / Javascript**

Use the API to generate the index of posts tagged with *featured*. Ref: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

**Theme Operators / CSS**

Use `{TagAsClasses}` variable, as mentioned by [unor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21309512/2312574), to visually hide everything but posts tagged with *featured*. The downsides far out way the good, (downloading content that isn't visually on the page, no index if no featured posts...)

**Theme Operators / Post Type**

Pick a specific post type and reserve it for feature posts only. You can create an index page using just one post type:

```
{block:IndexPage}
    {block:Posts}
        {block:Photo}
        /* Photo posts index page */
        {/block:Photo}
    {/block:Posts}
{/block:IndexPage}
```

**Redirect / Tagged URL**

Take advantage of Tumblr's URL scheme:

`xxx.tumblr.com/tagged/` always exists. Append the tag you want to see, to create a page of *featured* posts.

Then use your domain host to fetch `xxx.tumblr.com/tagged/featured` when every `xxx.tumblr.com` is visited.

This I haven't tested and is just a theory.

**Outro**

Whatever you decide, make sure you have an index page with content regardless. The API / Redirect solutions may causes issue with search engine indexing if there is no content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`{TagsAsClasses}` variable](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts):

> An HTML class-attribute friendly list of the post's tags.

Add it in your theme to your post markup. Then use CSS to hide all posts except those with the tag "featured".

Disadvantage:

- When the newest 10 (or whatever you configured as per-page post number) posts are *not* featured posts, the front page would show no posts at all.